# how to count the checkbox which was checked using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here, I used $watch to display the counter value.

But the counter value not increased yet,

To Count,

```
$scope.$watch('items', function(items){
var selectedItems = 0;
angular.forEach(items, function(item){
selectedItems += item.selected ? 1 : 0;
})
$scope.selectedItems = selectedItems;
}, true);
```

In UI,

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="item in items">
<label class="chkbox-holder cbox mbot10" for="List-{{$index}}"><input ng-model="item.Selected" type="checkbox" id="List-{{$index}}"><label for="List-{{$index}}"></label>{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

To display the counter value,

```
<div>Selected Items Length: {{selectedItems}}</div>
```

But still the counter is 0;

JSON Value from http service is,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "refCode": "",
    "name": "pragadees"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "refCode": "",
    "name": "pragadees"
  }......]
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Check the function is being fired at all with a console.log

Comment: It shows nothing @gillesc

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Please provide complete html with app and controller

Comment: Post more code so we see how items is changed over time. if it doesn't get changed you might need to run the counter code on it's on. Just create a named function, call it and use it as watch call back.

Comment: Currently am working on that. See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mtq4zbw5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just got a typo error. Your markup is bound to `item.Selected` while your JavaScript is checking for `item.selected`. Renaming them properly solves your problem. I'd recommend using lower key inside ot html.

```
<input ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" id="List-{{$index}}">
                      ^-- See here
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/worBOJ)

Comment: Am getting data from service without {selected:false}, @Aero

Comment: And what's the exact problem with that?

Comment: I saw it too, does it solve the issue? btw, adding a watch is not the solution

Comment: @Idris look my answer, it's already without watches. I use inner two way data binding stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you got a typo in your ng-model, it is `item.selected` not `item.Selected` that's maybe why it does not match nothing...

And this is how i'll write it, using basic angular two way data binding, no extra counters, watches, triggers, ....

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
      name: "Doe"
    }, {
      name: "Adam"
    }, {
      name: "Ado"
    }, {
      name: "Brown"
    }, {
      name: "Heather"
    }, {
      name: "Stan"
    }];
    
    $scope.itemsSelected = function() {
      return $scope.items.filter(function(i) {
        return i.selected
      }).length;
    }

  }

]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <h2>current active selected options {{ itemsSelected() }}</h2>

  <ul>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label for="List-{{$index}}">
        <input ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" id="List-{{$index}}">
        <label for="List-{{$index}}"></label>{{item.name}}</label>
    </div>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: it shows debugging errors.. filter is undefined function

Comment: this is strange per the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) this should work on arrays

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**ng-change**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 
$scope.items = [
  {name: 'A', value: 'a'},
  {name: 'B', value: 'b'},
  {name: 'C', value: 'c'},
  {name: 'D', value: 'd'},
  {name: 'E', value: 'e'}
];
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.change = function(e) {
  if(e){
    $scope.counter +=1;
  }else{
    if($scope.counter > 0) $scope.counter -=1;
  }
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="item in items">
<label class="chkbox-holder cbox mbot10" for="List-{{$index}}">
  <input ng-model="item.Selected" type="checkbox" id="List-{{$index}}" 
         ng-change="change(item.Selected)">
  <label for="List-{{$index}}"></label>{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
  Counter: {{counter}}
</div>
```

Comment: don't add extra watchers for that kind of things!